Pyspark DataFrame.write to SQL Server not respecting .option("truncate","true") and overwriting existing table schema
I am trying to write a Spark dataframe to an existing SQL Server table so that it's truncated before the write, leaving the schema preserved (specifically indices, constraints, and column types). My understanding based on the documentation is that using .mode("overwrite") with .option("truncate","true") should accomplish this goal.
However, with my code, the table is dropped and recreated without the indices, constraints, and with different data types (e.g, text instead of nvarchar, not null columns recreated to allow nulls). How can I write it to respect the truncate option?
df.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("truncate","true") \
  .option("driver", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("dbtable", "target_table") \
  .option("user", USER) \
  .option("password", PASS) \
  .option("batchsize", 20000) \
  .option("createTableColumnTypes","col1 int not null,"
                                   "col2 varchar(50) not null,"
                                   "col2 varchar(50) not null,"
                                   "col3 date not null,") \
  .save()

I am using Dataproc Serverless Spark runtime 2.2 which uses Spark 3.5.1

I am not sure whether the new data that you are inserting differs in schema structure from the existing one which might be causing it to get dropped.
1.You can try a few alternatives like first manually truncate it
truncate_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE target_table"
statement = connection.createStatement()

statement.executeUpdate(truncate_query)

2.Then use  .mode("append"), which will insert the data into the existing table.

The new data probably does have a different schema but I can't get the spark dataframe to match the existing sql server schema either. Part of the problem is spark.read() does not accept.schema() in conjunction with format("bigquery"). BigQuery is the original source of my data.
